# Fused Location API - Balanced in background but sometimes get GPS location

Tags: java, android, gps, location, google-play-services

I want to create a service to run in background using the Fused Location API from Google Services.

I put the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION access inside my manifest.

I've read somewhere that LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY won't use the GPS. It seems fine for me, because my service is running in background and I don't need it to be so accurate.

My question is: Since my service has 1 GoogleServiceAPI connection and this LocationRequest with balanced priority already requesting updates. If I call 
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(client), will it use GPS if the GPS is available on my cell and since I put FINE_LOCATION in my manifest or will it use my LocationRequest object settings?

Because I am planning to let this service requesting updates using balanced priority but sometimes reuse the same connection to get the last location in another thread.

Thanks!

Comment: you can do location.getProvider(), I think... which will tell you what provider the location came from.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs here: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

The precision of the location returned by this call is determined by the permission setting you put in your app manifest